# ValueError: no se pudo convertir la cadena en flotante: ' '

Tags: python, string, float, typeerror, int

No tengo idea de por que me da este error al momento de tratar de correr el código con una mainwindow de entrada de datos quisiera resolver el problema para poder ingresar numeros a float() y pueda darme respuesta a una operación, aun trato de resolverlo me serviría de mucho la ayuda
[image]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra el código _como texto, con formato_. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 1):

Una cadena vacia `''` no tiene valor numérico (ni siquiera cero).

Lo más sano al convertir entradas de teclado es considerar que puede fallar por muchas razones, y encerrar todo en un `try-except`

```
cadena = ''
try:
    valor = float(cadena)
except ValueError:
    valor = 0

print(valor)     # => 0
```

Si la cadena contiene un valor numérico, `float()` la convertira sin problemas; si tiene alguna falla o probable, se generara una excepción `ValueError` que será procesa en el `except`.

Con el `except` puedes controlar la acción posterior: convertir a cero, emitir un mensaje de error y volver a pedir, etc.